# Firebase database download chat data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download data for my chat from Firebase database(structure of data is bellow and It is recommended structure from official Firebase web).

```
"chats": {
      "one": {
        "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
        "timestamp": 1459361875666
      },
      "two": { ... }

},
"members": {
  "one": {
    "member1": "cxgF3EddyMWiYybXdMsYwu5YQsn1",
    "member2": "jdxBDm5MXBdX4zfGoEp9hgHqscn2"
  };
  "two": {
    "member1": "cxgF3EddyMWiYybXdMsYwu5YQsn1",
    "member2": "yGpTEPDfChVmUeEkzvCCY6IjQnA2"
  };
},
"messages": {
  "one": {
    "m1": {
      "name": "cxgF3EddyMWiYybXdMsYwu5YQsn1",
      "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875337
    },
    "m2": {
      "name": "jdxBDm5MXBdX4zfGoEp9hgHqscn2",
      "message": "Yes.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875689
    },
  },
  "two": { ... }
}
```

Now I'm trying just to check if I(as logged user) am involved in the conversation and download just the last message under chats/and particular chat number. Also I have to download a profile picture of another user that is involved in this chat and then add last message and this picture to PrefenceScreen.
Here is code:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("members");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>> m = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    };
                    Map<String, Object> map = snapshot.getValue(m);

                    if (map.get("member1").equals(myUID)) {
                        arrayList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                        arrayList.add(map.get("member2").toString());
                    } else if (map.get("member2").equals(myUID)) {
                        arrayList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                        arrayList.add(map.get("member1").toString());
                    }
                }
                mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

                for (int i=0, y=1; y<arrayList.size(); i+=2, y+=2) {
                    Log.i("Chat", arrayList.get(i));
                    StorageReference storageReference = mStorage.child("photos").child(arrayList.get(y));
                    try {
                        final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
                        final int finalI = i;
                        StorageTask<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> taskSnapshotStorageTask = storageReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());

                                Resources res = getResources();
                                final RoundedBitmapDrawable dr =
                                        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res, Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, false));
                                dr.setCornerRadius(500);

                                DatabaseReference myRef2 = database.getReference("chats").child(arrayList.get(finalI)).child("lastMessage");
                                myRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                        Log.d("TAG", "Value is: " + message);

                                        PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(getActivity());

                                        Preference preference = new Preference(getActivity());
                                        preference.setTitle(message);
                                        preference.setKey("Hej celkom v pohode");
                                        preference.setIcon(dr);
                                        preference.setSelectable(true);
                                        preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScrollingActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        });
                                        screen.addPreference(preference);
                                        setPreferenceScreen(screen);
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                                        // Failed to read value
                                        Log.w("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e ) {
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

The code is almost doing what It should. The problem is that it all the time adds just one Prefence because the screen.addPreference(preference); and setPreferenceScreen(screen); methods are inside onDataChange. Is there a way how to use methods after files are downloaded?
And also I think this code is messy and there must by simplier way to download all the data. You would be very thankful if you can help me with this. Thanks.